# How to have a image of a map cover background with marker images and resize properly?

Tags: html, css, image, image-resizing

So this may seem confusing and I know a plugin or google maps would be easier but this is what the company is demanding. Their UI/UX guy created the image of a world map (all the continents). They want the map to cover the entire background. Then they have images of the map markers they want placed on top in certain locations. Then you need to be able to hover over each and have a tooltip pop-up. All of that I have working but I cannot figure out how to get each marker to resize with the map image as the screen shrinks.

Here is what they want 
[image]

I have that working but only on full size heres what happens when the screen resizes

[image]

Here is the code I currently have

```js
    $(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
    })
```

```css
    .map {
        background-image: var(--boh-map-image),url("/images/map/BOH_map_01.jpg") !important;
        background: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100%, 100%;
        height: 75rem;
    }
    
     .marker-pin-midwest {
        width: 25px;
        height: 35px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 27.05rem;
        top: 197.3rem;
    }

    .marker-pin-northeast {
        width: 25px;
        height: 35px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 33.875rem;
        top: 197.6rem;
    }
```

```html
<section class="section-page-content map nomobile">
    <div class="container text-center">
        <a href="#" name="global-impact"></a>
        <h2 style="color: #359a89!important; text-transform:uppercase">Bridge of Hope Missions</h2>
    </div>

    <img class="marker-pin-midwest"
         src="~/images/map/map-marker_sm.png"
         data-toggle="tooltip"
         data-placement="top"
         data-html="true"
         title="<img width='175' height='175' src='/images/map/BOHMAP-midwest.png' /><br/><br/><b>MIDWEST</b><br/><p>Victims of tragedy across the region receive 120,000 pounds of relief funded by Bridge of Hope partners (IA, ND, AR)</p>" />

    <img class="marker-pin-northeast"
         src="~/images/map/map-marker_sm.png"
         data-toggle="tooltip"
         data-placement="top"
         data-html="true"
         title="<img width='175' height='175' src='/images/map/BOHMAP-northeast.png' /><br/><br/><b>NORTHEAST</b><br/><p>Bridge of Hope and partners deliver 120,000 pounds of aid to strengthen rescue workers and volunteers in the wake of 9/11</p>" />
</section>
```

If anyone knows a way to make this work as they want it to I'd appreciate the help just stuck on this one. Thanks

Comment: _“They want the map to cover the entire background.”_ - of what, exactly - the whole page? Without _any_ further restrictions? So if this was viewed on, say, a mobile device with a screen that was about twice as high as it was wide, you’d probably only see a middle strip of the whole thing - Africa and a bit on the sides maybe, but some of those markers would likely get cut off on the sides and disappear. Do “they” actually want that? If not, they should probably come up with a bit stricter requirements to begin with.

Comment: Getting something like this “responsive” in just the width dimension would be pretty trivial, in comparison - using percentages to position the markers usually works well in such cases, without requiring much extra effort.

Comment: Don't use a *background-image* - use an actual image  - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dgcha (or an SVG)

Comment: Map to cover just the entire background of that section so on the homepage you'll have a section with stats then underneath that a section with articles then under that the section with the map and they want the entire section covered no white-spaces or gaps

Comment: Paulie_D comment is what I used and it worked and solved my problem thank you.